# How to implement composite constraint or the equivalent of "is node key" in neo4j ogm?

Tags: neo4j, neo4j-ogm

I'm using Neo4j OGM version 2.1.3.

I used to have a `@Index (unique=true, primary=true)` on a specific attribute and things worked fine when `session.save(obj)` was executed.

It was correctly able to execute either a `CREATE` or a `MERGE` based on the unique constraint. However, now I need a composite constraint that spans 3 different attributes.

Since I couldn't find a means to specify a composite index using OGM, I've specified a `IS NODE KEY` constraint on those 3 properties/attributes outside of code (directly executing a CYPHER on Neo4j shell).

Now, after adding a relationship when I try to execute a `session.save(domainObj)`, I now get a `Node already exists with ...` exception since ogm tries to execute a `CREATE` query instead of a `MERGE`.

How do I provide a hint to OGM to not construct a `CREATE` but a `MERGE` ?

Or in other words, is there a way to specify a composite constraint in OGM so that I can get past this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this is not currently supported (neither in neo4j-ogm 2.1.x nor upcoming 3.0.0).

Please feel free to create a feature request at https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j-ogm/issues.